# How close could a 1 solar mass star get to our solar system without disrupting the planets' orbits

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, stars

Is there an easy way to calculate how close a star of given mass could get to our solar system without disrupting the orbits of the planets?
Just looking for a rough estimate, nothing too involved

Comment: the outer small planets were discovered by measuring the influence to the orbits of the inner ones, so it depends how much the orbits are disrupted.

Comment: Essentially how close could you get without throwing any of the planets out of the system, changing the order that they orbit in, or result in any of the planets colliding?